# Getting a 404 on /wd/hub/session when I try to connect to selenium grid remotely via Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I can see two remotes under the console but when I try to connect remotely and execute something it fails with a 404.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Remote(
   command_executor='http://ec2-184-72-129-183.compute-1.amazonaws.com:4444/wd/hub',
   desired_capabilities={'browserName': 'firefox'})
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
browser.quit()
```

Throws this exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "browser-shot.py", line 16, in <module>
    desired_capabilities={'browserName': 'firefox'})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 104, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 155, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 125, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: '<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>\n<title>Error 404 </title>\n</head>\n<body><h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2><pre>NOT_FOUND</pre>\n<p>RequestURI=/wd/hub/session</p><p><i><small><a href="http://jetty.mortbay.org/">Powered by Jetty://</a></small></i></p><br/>                                                \n<br/>                                                \n<br/>                                                \n<br/>                                                \n<br/>                                                \n<br/>                                                \n<br/>                                                \n<br/>                                                \n<br/>                                                \n<br/>                                                \n<br/>                                                \n<br/>                                                \n<br/>                                                \n<br/>                                                \n<br/>                                                \n<br/>                                                \n<br/>                                                \n<br/>                                                \n<br/>                                                \n<br/>                                                \n\n</body>\n</html>\n'
```

Comment: I have a similar problem.  It seems either /wd/hub/session isn't being served by selenium or the Remote is looking for a resource in the wrong place.

Comment: Its a shot in the dark, since i'm not familiar with Python bindings, but this could be connection related, i have several problems where i could connect to the grid via IDE but wasn't possible on Hudson/Jenkins.

Comment: I recomend you to remove the aws url from the example... you know, just in case :)

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't appear to be a python error. It seems like the machine you have your selenium server on is refusing requests.
In the error message, you have an 
    `<a href="http://jetty.mortbay.org/">Powered by Jetty://</a>`
which got me thinking that it is somehow related to Jetty.

I don't know much about Jetty, but you might want to look there for your answers.
One possible problem is that Jetty is also running on port 4444, but I can't say for sure, because I don't know how Jetty works.

EDIT

I should also add that I tried your setup on my local machine, to one of my servers (that doesn't have Jetty on it) and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: I think Jetty is the webserver that selenium grid runs on top of.  If Jetty were running as a separate process there, wouldn't either Jetty or the grid throw a binding error when starting, saying the port is in use?

Comment: Wait, are you using the standalone server for selenium?

Comment: Also, can you post your selenium version?

Comment: I'm using selenium grid 1.0.8.  I'm starting the grid with `ant launch-hub`

Comment: Could you try to use the standalone server that is here: http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar

Comment: that was it.  "I'll change this to use a port that nobody uses ... like 4444."  oops.

Answer (score 1):

Try running selenium hub using_

```
-port 5555
```

And then configure clients with also:

```
-port 5555
```

I think is an issue with another software using port 4444 or selenium is not starting in that port correctly.